# import 3 digit field with leading zero

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-3.0, import-from-excel, oledbdataadapter

ASP.NET, C#, MVC 3, Code First project

I'm trying to import data from an Excel spreadsheet.  I've formated all cells as Text.
A sample row in the Import worksheet is as follows.

```
Account             Card               ThreeCode  Route  
04562954830287127   32849321890233127  183        154839254 
04562954830287128   32849321890233128  233
04562954830287129   32849321890233129  082
04562954830287130   32849321890233130  428
```

When I run in debug and drill down into the ds DataSet the Account and Card columns are imported as strings, the 3-Digit and Route columns are imported as doubles.  The problem arises with the 3 digit number starting with 0 (082) in data row 3.  It gets imported as a System.DBNull and is empty.  I need to be able to import 3 digit codes with leading zeros.  Is there a way to force the import to be all strings or another way to approach this problem?  I searched the web for and haven't found a solution.  This will run from a browser so anything to do with the registry, dll or ini files on the local machine is not an option.  The import code is below.  Thank you in advance for any help.

```
public ActionResult ExcelToDS(string Path = "C;\File.xls")
{ 
  string strConn = "Provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + Path + "; " + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

  OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
  conn.Open(); string strExcel = "";
  OleDbDataAdapter myCommand = null;
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  strExcel = "select * from [Import$]";
  DataSet ds = null; 
  myCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(strExcel, strConn);
  ds = new DataSet(); myCommand.Fill(ds, "table1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to make this work consistently.  The work around I came up with is to add 1000 to the ThreeCode column in the Excel workbook.  You are then able to import the data into a dataset.  Then when the data is read out you simply strip off the "1" preifx.  Here is my inline method to do that.

```
public static string last3(this string instring)
{ int len = instring.Length - 3; string outstring = instring.Substring(len, 3); return outstring; }
```

Which you can call in the code with:

```
card.3Dig = code.last3();
```

'card' and '3dig' are the class and field being populated.  'code' is the 4 digit dataset data.

Comment: By sampling all the rows as per the value below, the excel driver should be querying every field in that column and if it finds something that seems like its a string then it treats all the data as a string. I've written a production app that worked off of this same fix after quite a bit of  research in applications experiencing the exact same issue you've mentioned and resolved it this way. Also to note., I used the 64 bit driver because of max length issues, but that shouldn't matter here that I recall.

Comment: You could try setting IMEX as per  http://jingyangli.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/imex1-revisit-and-typeguessrows-setting-change-to-0-watch-for-performance/
 and also make sure you set the reg value in the right location (the sas link discusses it, prob something on MS's site too but this came up first : )   http://support.sas.com/kb/35/563.html

Comment: As I said before since it is a 3 digit number the testing determines that it is a double, there are no cells with a string in it. I tried prefixing the first 8 rows of data with a single quote but from row 9 on it returns System.DBNull.  If 200 hundred rows were being imported there is not a practical way of prefixing all of them with a single quote.  Adding 1000 can be done with a simple formula =D2+1000, filled down through all rows and then its values pasted back into the original column.

Comment: This is not a mixed data issue.  Slowing the import down by sampling more rows is not going to fix it, besides the fact I do not want to be messing with my end users’ registries.  Curiously it interprets the 17 digit Account number with a leading zero as a string but not the 3 digit number even though all cells are formatted as text in the worksheet.  Have you been able to replicate the problem with a 3 digit number?  The problem appears to be a bug with dealing with very short numbers formatted as text with a leading zero.

Comment: Maybe I missed this. It sounds like a mixed data issue - the driver interprets it as numerical and then sees a leading zero and interprets as text and thus nulls? What's the data type that comes across? Is a third party driver possible? They avoid all of this garbage :) also is this xls or xlsx open XML format?

Comment: The 16 and 17 digit numbers are interpreted as strings.
The 3 digit number as either a double or System.DBNull.
XLS.  All cells formatted as text.
I don’t get your comment ‘leading zero interprets as text and thus nulls'.  If it interpreted it as text why wouldn’t it return a 3 character string (ex. 083)?  It seems more likely since it interprets the non-leading zero 3 digits as doubles it considers the leading zero a double, therefore invalid and therefore returns a System.DBNull.  Again the problem is not mixed data, it is that the 3 digit text cell is interpreted as a double not a string.

Comment: More sampling of the column of 3 digit numbers isn't going to change that.

Comment: Yes - it should. I think you are missing the issue, or there's behavior here Im forgetting. The excel driver samples the first say 8 rows. It sees 120-128 for example. These come over as say.. doubles. Now it then encounters 012 and say 'ut oh, this doesnt fit out double format - this looks to be text, so since we are already using doubles and now we have text, we have to return DbNull. A single column cannot return more than one data type, this the null - that behavior I'm 100% certain on.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear above to answer directly "If it interpreted it as text why wouldn’t it return a 3 character string (ex. 083)? I"  because the driver doesnt do that. A column is only a single data type. If its already determined to be double, every single cell in that column must either be double, or it will return a null. On the other hand if you can get it to interpret it as text for everything, then it will always return the real text in the column and you can convert it -hence the advantage of increased sampling.

Comment: Also to note - your solution here stating there isn't a way to make this work consistently - there is - you just seemingly can't follow it because of the reg changes on the client : ) I've done this before and it works consistently but true - it unfortunately involves a registry change. There's always third party libraries (infragistics, etc - theres a ton of them that dont have this issue)

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes the joys of the excel driver. What happens is it makes a determination from the first say ten rows on the data type, anything outside of that format becomes null.

Solutions are to use a more robust third party driver usually costing something, or set the registry key to fully sample all of the rows rather than the default 8.

Check out the link here for TypeGuessRows
http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

HKLM\Software\Wow5432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel
Set the value TypeGuessRows equal to zero

Comment: Most of the rows in the "threecode" column contain three digit numbers.  It doesn't seem that sampling more rows is going to get it to interpret it as a string.  If it doesn't interpret it as a string I don't see how it is going to be able to retain the leading 0.